# Click event on javascript createn div

Tags: javascript, html

Here I have a html

```
<div style="width: 200px;height:200px;padding:50px;background-color: lightcyan" id="maindiv" onclick="subdiv()"></div>
```

And javascript function for greating a subdiv

```
function subdiv() {
    var p = document.getElementById('maindiv');
    var s = document.createElement('div');
    s.setAttribute('id','subdiv');
    p.appendChild(s);
    var s2 = document.getElementById('subdiv');
    s2.style.height = '100px';
    s2.style.width = '100px';
    s2.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}
```

And here I **want** to do an event outside document.getElementById('subdiv'):

```
document.addEventListener('click',function() {
    alert('hello world');
});
```

**How to avoid** the alert('hello world') reaction on clicking the subdiv, and how to do, that works EXACTLY ONCE in every click outside the subdiv? I like possible simple response without a jquery. https://jsfiddle.net/hx2u6j35/
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Div tag is not properly append to the maindiv so I have created myself and preventing child tag from calling parent function

```js
function subdiv() {
  var p = document.getElementById('maindiv');
  var s = document.createElement('div');
  s.setAttribute('id', 'subdiv');
  s.setAttribute('onclick', 'return false;');
  p.appendChild(s);
  var s2 = document.getElementById('subdiv');
  s2.style.height = '100px';
  s2.style.width = '100px';
  s2.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}

document.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('hello world');
});

$("#subdiv").on('click', function(e) {
  alert("subdiv");
  return false; //THIS WON'T CALL PARENT FUNCTION OR YOU CAN USE e.stopPropagation
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 200px;height:200px;padding:50px;background-color: lightcyan" id="maindiv" onclick="subdiv()">
  <div id="subdiv" style="height:100px;width:100px;background-color:green"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use `event.target` to grab the Element on which `event` is invoked.

```js
function subdiv() {
  var p = document.getElementById('maindiv');
  var s = document.createElement('div');
  s.setAttribute('id', 'subdiv');
  p.appendChild(s);
  var s2 = document.getElementById('subdiv');
  s2.style.height = '100px';
  s2.style.width = '100px';
  s2.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.id == 'maindiv') {
    alert('hello world');
  }
});
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px;height:200px;padding:50px;background-color: lightcyan" id="maindiv" onclick="subdiv()"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable [event-capturing](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing) by passing another argument to the event handler

```
document.addEventListener('click',function() {
    alert('hello world');
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have an error when running this code.. The subdiv function is not available for the "onclick" function..

Get rid of the onclick attribute by using this :

```
document.addEventListener('click',function( _event ) {
    if( _event.target.id === "maindiv" ){
        subdiv();
    }else{
        alert('hello world');
    }
});
```

With this, you can avoid anything when you want..